# Upload an embed image?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am wondering how I can make my bot upload an embedded image to a Discord channel. I know how to make it send embeds, but how do I upload an embedded image? Is it even possible with discord.py?
Keep in mind I am not referring to the thumbnail image you can have in an embed image, I am wondering if you even can upload an embed image using Python. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach a file in an embed (Discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422822/attach-a-file-in-an-embed-discord-py)

Comment: See the post linked above for the updated solution as discord.py has changed and the answer here is now obsolete.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To send an image in an embed, use the `set_image` method of the embed:

```
e = discord.Embed()
e.set_image(url="https://discordapp.com/assets/e4923594e694a21542a489471ecffa50.svg")
```

To send a file from your PC, use the `send_file` method in async branch or the `send` method in rewrite branch.

```
# Async
await bot.send_file(channel, "filepath.png", content="...", filename="...")

# Rewrite
file = discord.File("filepath.png", filename="...")
await channel.send("content", file=file)
```

Comment: As the image URL, can I just place something like `https://i.imgur.com/5nqpFiF.jpg`? I don't get the TypeError anymore, but now nothing happens, might have something to do with the URL.

Comment: Direct image links like that *should* work. When you send the embed to the channel, it should add the image at that URL into the embed.

Comment: is there a way to set the image from a local directory?

Comment: What is the difference between 'Async' and 'Rewrite'?

Comment: When the answer was written, the discord.py on PyPI was version 0.16, or the Async branch.
Now though, the current version is 1.x which is Rewrite branch.
Both are here because both have been available to use for years, but only recently was Rewrite made into the main branch on PyPI

Comment: @SamRockett Ah thanks! I wrote my program to be `try: Rewrite  except AttributeError: Async` to support both 1.x and legacy 0.x versions!

Comment: For those looking to use a local image for an embed, check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578927/use-a-local-file-as-the-set-image-file-discord-py/61579108#61579108