# Discord does not embed link when sent by my bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, discord, discord.py

My code works fine and the bot sends the link, but Discord does not recognize it as one and does not embed it. When I copy and paste it myself, it then recognizes it as a link and embed the image. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


if message.content.startswith(".dog"):

    response = requests.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
    soupRaw = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    soupBackend = str(soupRaw).split("message")
    soup2 = soupBackend[1]
    soup3 = soup2[3:]
    soup = soup3[:-20]

    await bot.send_message(message.channel, soup)
```

Here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuS22.jpg

Does anyone know how to make it embed the link when it is sent by my bot? Thanks for the help!

Edit: I am not trying to send an embedded message, I am trying to send a link that will BE embedded by Discord, as shown in my example. This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send an embed via my Discord bot, w/python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862112/how-can-i-send-an-embed-via-my-discord-bot-w-python)

Comment: @bboll Nope not a duplicate. Please read my question. I am not trying to send an embedded message, I am trying to have Discord embed the link I am sending with the bot. Completely different things.

Comment: [Read the API](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed). You are trying to send an embedded message because it will not automatically create one for you. [I found another duplicate question that perhaps helps you better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515361/upload-an-embed-image). `e.set_image(url=soup)`. Then you would call it with a different parameter passing your embed object: `await bot.send_message(message.channel, embed=e)`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but - you could replace the five lines starting with "soup" with simply `url = response.json()['message']`. BeautifulSoup is doing nothing here besides mangling the JSON response from the api.

Comment: @bboll you still are confusing the difference between an embedded message and an embedded image. Please see the difference between an embedded message and an embed of an image here: https://imgur.com/a/7xXJS I understand how to send an embedded message. Very simple. But when a link is sent in discord, Discord automatically embeds the image in the chat. When my bot posts the link to

Comment: The question, Discord does not display the image. When a user does it, it does. Please see original imgur post in my question for an example of that. That is my question, NOT an embedded MESSAGE.

Comment: To clarify even more: When the link is sent by the bot (it does end with .jpg), Discord does not recognize

Comment: That it is a link, so it does not download and embed the image inside of the chat. But when a user sends the same link, it does. My question is how to make Discord recognize the link is an image when sent by a bot.

Comment: @MarkW That image you posted is of an embedded message. Did you check that your bot's role has Embed Links allowed in permissions? I don't see why you wouldn't just construct an embedded message with an image since you are aware of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but if anyone is viewing this answer for later; I believe the problem is that your variable `soup` contains escape characters (backward slashes) for every forward slash, e.g. `https:\\/\\/images.dog.ceo\\/breeds\\/maltese\\/n02085936_4480.jpg`.

Sending this as a message (even as a regular user) shows the link as it should look, but does not automatically create an embed for it. You can replace the backslashes with the function `soup.replace("\\", "")`.

I would however recommend a completely different approach as the `response` object has a `.content` attribute which is in json format and can easily be parsed, and used as a python `dict`, using the builtin `import json` library (It will automatically leave the escape codes for you and you don't have to worry about string length for response.text).

`soup = json.loads(response.content).get("message")` should do the trick.