# Discord Python Bot - Bot's messages not auto-embedding links/images/etc

Tags: hyperlink, embed, discord, discord.py

I"m trying something very simple, I'm just having a discord bot echo certain messages in certain channels into one channel, but much like the person here:
[Discord does not embed link when sent by my bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252094/discord-does-not-embed-link-when-sent-by-my-bot)
My bot's messages aren't auto-embedding.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using, I removed a bunch of the unrelated stuff in-between.

````
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
    return
    if (message.channel.name != 'discussion'):
        if message.channel.category != None:
            print(f'Posting message in {message.channel.category.name} {message.channel.name} from {message.author.name} to {chnglogchannel.name}\n')
            if message.content.startswith("```"):
                await chnglogchannel.send("```From {0} in {1} {2}\n{3}```".format(message.author.name, message.channel.category.name, message.channel.name, (message.content).strip('`')))
            else:
                await chnglogchannel.send("```From {0} in {1} {2}\n{3}```".format(message.author.name, message.channel.category.name, message.channel.name, message.content))
        else:
            print(f'Posting message in {message.channel.name} from {message.author.name} to {chnglogchannel.name}\n')
            if message.content.startswith("```"):
                await chnglogchannel.send("```From {0} in {1}\n{2}```".format(message.author.name, message.channel.name, (message.content).strip('`')))
            else:
                await chnglogchannel.send("```From {0} in {1}\n{2}```".format(message.author.name, message.channel.name, message.content))
        return
````

I thought maybe it was a channel permission issue, but the bot's role has full permissions to do everything in the channel it's echoing to.

Do I need to manually parse out http links and/or images/videos/etc? Or should Discord  be treating the bot messages like any other users' messages?

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can always manually send an [embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed) with the message.