# AIOHTTP meme command discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, aiohttp

I'm making a discord bot and I'm trying to make a random meme command and here's my error and code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def meme(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="meme", description="test")

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            embed.set_image(res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            await client.say(embed=embed)
```

```
Ignoring exception in command meme
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\atill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\atill\Downloads\Epic Bot\server.py", line 165, in meme
    embed.set_image(res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
TypeError: set_image() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\atill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\atill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\atill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: set_image() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I'm not sure how to make it so it is in an embed aswell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the error, the function `set_image(url)` takes only 1 argument, and you gave it 2. And for the embed message look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515361/upload-an-embed-image) thread.

Comment: The important thing to note here is that `set_image` takes a single *positional* argument, which is the `Embed` instance the method is called on.  The url should be passed as a keyword argument: `embed.set_image(url=...)`.

Answer (score 3):

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def meme(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="")

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: How does this even work though? The command works but I don't understand it. Can you show me what it does?

Answer (score 1):

My personal suggestion for you is to use `https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/dankmemes` for pulling memes.And if you're interested in adding a title use this command to add a title to your embed:

```py
title = res['data']['children'][random.randint(0,25]["data"]["title"]I
```

Comment: I think you meant "title = res['data']['children'][random.randint(0,25)]["data"]["title"]"