# Attach a file in an embed (Discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am currently writing a discord bot with `discord.py Rewrite` and I want to attach an image onto an embed but I can't figure it out.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embeds

crafting_table = Embed(title="Crafting Table", description=discord.File("./images/Crafting_Table_GUI.png"))

@client.command()
async def Info(ctx, *, question):
    if "crafting table" in question:
        await ctx.send(embed=crafting_table)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is possible. Let me give an example.

```
# Rewrite
file = discord.File("filename.png") # an image in the same folder as the main bot file
embed = discord.Embed() # any kwargs you want here
embed.set_image(url="attachment://filename.png")
# filename and extension have to match (ex. "thisname.jpg" has to be "attachment://thisname.jpg")
await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=file)
```

If it is in a directory, you may do discord.File("images/filename.png", filename="filename.png"), but for the attachment:// url it is still just the name, no directory.

Comment: This seems to not work if the filepath in the `discord.File` is an absolute path, and will instead send the image outside of the embed like a normal file.

Comment: `url = 'attachment://image.png'   file = discord.File(image_url, filename="image.png")` worked for me (as long as `url` and `filename` match, it's fine. `image_url` is the actual file path, for example, `images/filename.png`).

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [documentation for discord.embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed)

To set a file in an embed, a url is required, you cannot put an image into an embed via your local host.

To set image on an embed, you can use `embed.set_image(url="<your image link>")`

Heres an example -

```
@client.command(name="Info")
async def Info(ctx, *, question):
    if question == "crafting table":
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0xffffff)
        embed.set_image(url="<your image link>")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

You cannot directly attach an Image from your PC into an embed.
So you will just need to send the files as attachments, rather than a embed, here is how to do it -

1. Put the image you want to send in the same folder as your Bot.
   and then use this code -

```
@client.command(name="Info")
async def Info(ctx, *, question):
    if question == "crafting table":
        await ctx.send(file=discord.file(fp="<your_file_name>.jpg", filename="image.jpg"))
```

**NOTE -** Change the extension of the file accordingly. In the example I have used ".jpg".

Comment: just head over to https://imgbb.com/upload and upload your image, after uploading, copy the link of the image, and put it in the `embed.set_image(url="<your image link>")`

Comment: 1. Go to https://imgbb.com/upload
2. Click on ` browse from your computer`
3. Select the Image from your PC
4. Copy the link of that image you just uploaded.
5. put the link inside `embed.set_image(url="<your image link>")`
Got it?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Async
await bot.send_file(channel, "filepath.png", content="...", filename="...")

# Rewrite
file = discord.File("filepath.png", filename="...")
await channel.send("content", file=file)
```