# How to embed an image with a url on discord with a bot (using python)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515361/upload-an-embed-image) which gives the `embed` and `set_image` method. I have tried that combined with sending the embed like the following code:

```
embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "Title",
        description = "Body of the embed. This is the description"
        )
imageurl = 'https://discordapp.com/assets/e4923594e694a21542a489471ecffa50.svg'
embed.set_image(url = imageurl)
embed.set_footer(text = 'This is a footer')
embed.set_author(name = 'Author name')
      
await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

However, I just see an embed without the picture:

[image]

I have checked for it to have the proper permissions (I think)? with attach files and embed links given to the bot role. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: did you try with other type of image - i.e PNG, JPG ? Did you try with image on other server? Maybe it doesn't allow for links to discord.

Comment: @furas I got it working with the url that I actually want to use -- I had an extra `/` at the end which caused all the problems... I can't figure out why this is not allowed though. (@moderators since the purpose of this question is fulfilled, you can close the question, but I would like an answer why svg files and/or discord files  don't work)

Comment: Stackoveflow is not forum - question is no closed when you get answer. It can be closed only if it is useless.

Comment: try in browser this link with extra / and you will see that it doesn't give image so it can't be displayed. And discord doesn't know that it has to be without /

Comment: it does display the image though

Comment: I tested with other `.svg` and it also doesn't display. It seems discord doesn't work with `.svg` (which is vector image) and you have to use bitmap images like `.png`, `.jpg`, `.gif`

Comment: I found this on discord forum: [Add a preview for .svg images – Discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360032379131-Add-a-preview-for-svg-images) and it confirm that discord can't use `.svg`

Comment: Oh got it. They used this image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515361/upload-an-embed-image) so I thought I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, discord embeds do not accept SVGs. If I try this same code with a JPG/PNG, it works. SVG however, not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).