# discord.py embed avatar command

Tags: python, discord.py

So I've been trying to make a discord.py command that sends the mentioned users avatar in a embed.

this is what i have so far

```
@client.command()
async def v1_3(ctx, user: discord.User):
    avurl = user.avatar_url
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{user.name}", description=f"{avurl}", color=0xf20202)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload an embed image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515361/upload-an-embed-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what your doing is putting the url in the description field, what you wanna do is:

```
@client.command()
async def v1_3(ctx, user: discord.User):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.name}' , color = 0xf20202)
        avurl = user.avatar_url
        e.set_image(url=f'{avurl}')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

this will send the embed with the users avatar